# Form to upload more than one image

Tags: javascript

I have a form that I use to upload more than one image, when I have upload all the images i can click button to obtain info from image and save info in array for each image.

Now I have a problem in my form because I save only the last image info, so for example if I load 2 images, the first image is basically lost.

this is the index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Coords Images</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    <script src="exif.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p><input multiple type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="image" onchange="loadFile(event)" style=""></p>
    <input type="submit" onclick="saveImage()" />
    <p class="cont" id="preview"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

and the functions.js

```
var myImages = []
var arrayInfo = []
function saveImage() {
    console.log("myImages ", myImages)
    myImages.forEach(el => {

        readUrl(el)
        console.log("el ", el)
        EXIF.getData(el.files[0], function () {

            EXIF.getData(this, () => {
                console.log(this)
                if (Object.keys(this.exifdata).length > 0) {
                    let foundLatLong

                    //display camera details    
                    // camera_details(this.exifdata)
                    //display image details
                    foundLatLong = generate_lat_lang(this)
                    console.log("foundLatLong ", foundLatLong)
                    arrayInfo.push(foundLatLong)
                    console.log("arrayInfo ", arrayInfo)
                } else {
                    noDataAvailable()
                }

            });

        });
    })
}

function loadFile(event) {
    console.log("document ", document.getElementById('image'))
    for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
        image.id = "output";
        image.width = "200";
        document.querySelector(".cont").appendChild(image);
        myImages.push(document.getElementById('image'))
    }
};

function readUrl(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        console.log("document.getElementById(preview) ", document.getElementById("preview"))
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById("preview").src = e.target.result
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

function generate_lat_lang(imageData = '') {
    let latitudine
    let longitudine
    let imageInfo = {
        name: imageData.name,
        latitudine: 0,
        longitudine: 0
    }
    //geting cordinates of latitude
    var latDegree = imageData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[0].numerator;
    var latMinute = imageData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[1].numerator;
    var latSecond = imageData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[2].numerator / imageData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[2].denominator;

    latitudine = (latDegree + (latMinute / 60) + (latSecond / 3600)).toFixed(8);;


    //geting cordinates of longitude
    var lonDegree = imageData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[0].numerator;
    var lonMinute = imageData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[1].numerator;
    var lonSecond = imageData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[2].numerator / imageData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[2].denominator;
    longitudine = (lonDegree + (lonMinute / 60) + (lonSecond / 3600)).toFixed(8);
    console.log("latitutide ", latitudine, longitudine)
    imageInfo.latitudine = latitudine
    imageInfo.longitudine = longitudine

    return imageInfo
}
```

I think the problem is in my loadFile function

How can I upload and save info for more than one image and not the last one only?

EDIT.

stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-n56n27?file=index.js

Comment: Try saving it in a global scope array in blob format until you send it to the server

Comment: Thank you for answer, so you suggest to change my myImages array to global?

Comment: Hold on, I'm trying to fully understand the massive code you pasted

Comment: Basically I think the only functions that are interested are the loadFile and saveImage

Comment: Can you explain what it looks like when image is lost? Disappears in myImages?

Comment: Yes in my saveImage function I make a forEach, and then a EXIF.getData, now I'm expecting that the forEach make a cycle in all the images, while it does on the last one. So if I have two image uploaded, I make a forEach only in the last image twice

Comment: "myImages.push(document.getElementById('image'))" in the loadFile saves the entire input:file element in the array. But is the save file I see that you are trying to access only the first file "el.files[0]"

Comment: I can't see that you are running cycle on images, but doing it on the same element "input". Did you notice that?

Comment: And I suppose that it is the error! I don't understand how to cycle in image

Comment: I have check what you suggest the el.files[0], I have tried to see the el.files and it print two times the last image